# How to estimateGas when calling 'exactInputSingle' from Uniswap V3 router?

Tags: typescript, cryptography, ethers.js, uniswap

I need to estimate gas and show it to the user, but the problem is when I execute code below, I get an `Invalid ENS name (argument='name'...`

```
uniswap.swapRouterContract.estimateGas.exactInputSingle([swapTxInputs])
                .then(gasEstimate => {
                    console.log(`Estimated Gas: ${gasEstimate.toString()}`);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
```

the swapTxInputs is:

```
const swapTxInputs = [
                fromToken.address,
                toToken.address,
                BigNumber.from(CryptoConfig.UNISWAP_V3_MEDIUM_FEE),
                dexWallet.walletAddress,
                CryptoConfig.SWAP_DEADLINE,
                amountInWei,
                BigNumber.from(CryptoConfig.UNDEFINED_VALUE),
                BigNumber.from(CryptoConfig.UNDEFINED_VALUE)
            ]
```

The swap is works perfectly, but not working when trying to estimate gas.

Estimate gas works when calculating gas for wrap, unwrap, transfer. Only swap estimations fails.

```
const wrapped = fromToken.address;
            const wrappedContract = new Contract(wrapped, nativeTokenABI, dexWallet.wallet);
            const wrappedBalance = await wrappedContract.balanceOf(dexWallet.walletAddress);

            const gasEstimate: BigNumber = await wrappedContract.estimateGas['deposit']({value: ethers.utils.parseEther(amount.toString()), gasPrice: dexWallet.providerGasPrice});
            totalGas = totalGas.add(gasEstimate);
            console.log(`Wrapping estimated Gas: ${ethers.utils.formatUnits(gasEstimate.mul(dexWallet.providerGasPrice), fromToken.decimals)}`);
```

Comment: ENS full error

Error: invalid ENS name (argument="name", value=["0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270","0x3c499c542cEF5E3811e1192ce70d8cC03d5c3359",{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x01f4"},"MyAddress",{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x65a6a737"},{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0xb1a2bc2ec50003"},{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"}], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=providers/5.4.5)